# PowerPoint - How to attach a label to a line graphic

Tags: graphics, powerpoint

When you add a polygon shape to PowerPoint, you can attach/embed a textbox inside it. When you move or rotate the polygon shape, the text adjusts with it.

How can I do this with a line shape?

In the example below, I rotated and moved both boxes, and the text and lines updated automatically. The label didn't move and is no longer associated with the line.

How can I "attach" the label to the line?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most shapes have a text frame; that's the "container" for any text in the shape.  Lines don't have a text frame, so can't hold text.

So you cheat.

Simplest dodge would be to create a separate text box and group it with the line.

Or you can draw a rectangle, give it no outline, make its fill the color you want your line to be, then set its height to whatever line width you want.  The rectangle *can* hold text. By default, the text will sit atop the line, which isn't what you want here, so add a line feed to the beginning or end of the text to bump it below or above the line slightly.

Comment: this doesn't do _quite_ what I want since the polygon/line isn't automatically connected to the boxes the way that default lines are, so it doesn't move when they move - but it's a good workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Grouping text box to connector (line) in PPT 2016 (365) didn't even work for me at all.  No movement.  My trick: group the "yes" & "no" labels for a logic diamond to the logic object instead of to the lines.